# Issues with external file being stored in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, io

the problem I have today is that I have to create an arrayList and store info about movies from an external file in it. However, I then have to create a method that ADDS movie  in my arrayList. The problem is that it has to compare if the movie that is being added already exists in my arrayList. However, I just know how to read from the file and store it in my arrayList as a string. Any idea on how I could make it work?

My inventory class does the following ( at the moment):

```
    private ArrayList<String> movieList;

    public Inventory() throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = null;
        this.movieList = new ArrayList<String>();

     try {
             br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movieBase"));
              String str;
               while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  movieList.add(str);
                  System.out.println(str);
                }
            br.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void addMovie(String title, int year, int duration, double rating){

        movie newMovie = new movie (title, year,duration,rating);
        for(String str : movieList){

        }
    }       
}
```

EDIT** ( I thought it would be a good idea to include this) My external file looks as follow:

Captain America: The Winter Soldier - 2014 - 136 - 3.5

Birdman - 2014 - 119 - 3.7

Batman - 1989 - 126 - 3.2

Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull - 2008 - 122 - 2.6

King Kong - 1933 - 100 - 3.8

Duck Soup - 1933 - 68 - 3.5

Casablanca - 1942 - 102 - 3.9

Citizen Kane - 1941 - 119 - 3.7

Chinatown - 1974 - 130 - 3.6

The Godfather - 1972 - 175 - 3.9

Skyfall - 2012 - 143 - 3.2

Forest Gump - 1994 - 142 - 3.8

The Matrix - 1999 - 136 - 3.4

Jaws - 1975 - 124 - 3.3

Lawrence of Arabia - 1962 - 216 - 3.5

An American in Paris - 1951 - 113 - 2.9

Comment: a `if` statement and `equals` method inside the loop would do the trick

Comment: The contents of your `ArrayList` and what your adding to it don't seem compatible (You define it as containing `movie`, but are adding `String`s?).  You need to look into overriding the `equals` method, then you can simply use `ArrayList#contains`

Comment: well the idea is that my movie object isn't a string. So if I compare, eclipse just tells me it's not able to compare a string to a movie object :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer oops should change that. I caught that error earlier, still didn't change much ! haha

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that it has to compare if the movie that is being added
>   already exists in my arrayList.

It sounds like you want to use a `Set`, maybe even a SortedSet.  `List`'s allow for duplicates where `Set`'s do not, so if you insist on using a `List` you would have to explicitly check if your `List` 'contains' the given movie.

You'll need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method on your Movie object to do this.

**EDIT**:
Now that you've indicated your requirements more clearly (you want a frequency table), I would say that you can use a Map (e.g `Map<Movie, Integer>`).

Comment: well I want duplicates to be allowed. I mean I would just increase its quantity. Ultimately, I just want to see if it exist so I can modify its quantity. What I find is mind boggling is how to read the file THEN compare it to my Movie object

Comment: Then i would consider using a Map.  Something like: Map<Movie, Integer> should do.  For convenience I'd use Guava's MultiMap

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding `equals` and `hashcode` methods? Read item 8 and item 9 in [this](http://jtechies.blogspot.in/2012/07/item-8-obey-general-contract-when.html?m=1) article. 
1. override equals in Movie class

```
public class Movie{
    // properties and methods
    // override hashcode


@override
public boolean equals(Object obj){

  if( this == obj) {
       return true;
  }

  if(!( obj instanceof Movie)){
        return false;
   }

  Movie input = (Movie) obj;


  if(this.gerTitle().equls(input.getTitle()) && 
      this.getYear().equals(input.getyear()) &&
      this.getDuration().equals(input.getDuration()) &&
      this.getRating().equals(input.getrating())){

          return true;
  }


   return false;

}

}
```

2. From ArraList of String, create an ArrayList of Movie and populate it.

```
 
    public void addMovie(String title,int year, int duration, double rating)
              {
                // List to store all your movies
                List movieObjList=  new ArrayList();
                for(String str : movieList)
                  {
                   //Split the string to get title, year, duration and reading separately
                   String s[] = str.split("-");
                   //Create Movie object
                   Movie m = new Movie ();
                   m.setTitle(s[0]);
                   m.setYear(s[1]);
                   m.setDuration(s[2]);
                   m.getrating(s[3]);

                   //check movieObjList contains this movie already and do the logic.
                   if(movieObjList.contains(m))
                   {
                     // logic to increase the count
                   }
                   //add the movie to list
                   movieObjList.add(m);
                 }
            }
```